# How to get a dataframe in hierarchical indexs which are unique values of a feature

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I get a `df` as follows:

```
    tradeMonth  tradeDay    tradeMoney  plate
0   12.0        2           2000.0      BK00052
1   11.0        1           2000.0      BK00052
2   2.0         0           16000.0     BK00028
3   4.0         1           1600.0      BK00028
4   2.0         2           2900.0      BK00017
```

And I want to use `groupby('plate')` to get a `df` as follows:

```
    plate       tradeMonth      tradeDay    tradeMoney  
    BK00052     12.0            2           2000.0      
                11.0            1           2000.0      
    BK00028     2.0             0           16000.0     
                4.0             1           1600.0      
    BK00017     2.0             2           2900.0
```

And I have tried to use `df.unique()` to get the unique values of `plate` as the hierarchical indexs. But what I should implement it next puzzles.
Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If create `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['plate','tradeMonth','tradeDay'])
print (df)
                             tradeMoney
plate   tradeMonth tradeDay            
BK00052 12.0       2             2000.0
        11.0       1             2000.0
BK00028 2.0        0            16000.0
        4.0        1             1600.0
BK00017 2.0        2             2900.0
```

---

It seems data in first level are unique, but not, only are not displayed by default. For verify change `multi_sparse` to `False`: [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object):

> We’ve 'sparsified' the higher levels of the indexes to make the console output a bit easier on the eyes. Note that how the index is displayed can be controlled using the `multi_sparse option`:

```
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print (df)
                             tradeMoney
plate   tradeMonth tradeDay            
BK00052 12.0       2             2000.0
BK00052 11.0       1             2000.0
BK00028 2.0        0            16000.0
BK00028 4.0        1             1600.0
BK00017 2.0        2             2900.0
```

Answer (score 0):

its simple

```
df = df.groupby('plate').groups
print df
```

You don't need to mention unique here.